# Android Bitmap problem

Tags: java, android, bitmap, video-streaming, mjpeg

I have a motion JPEG stream that is put on a canvas in Android.  My problem is that at the bottom right of the canvas there is a little, gray, pixelated bar.  It kinda of disappears and re-appears.  I don't have this issue on other platforms that use the same stream, so i'm guessing its an Android problem.  Here is my code:

```
Canvas canvas = null;
            try
            {

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(notifi.imgData, 0, notifi.imgData.length);
                if (bmp == null)
                    System.out.println("Skipping invalid MJpeg frame");
                else
                {
                    canvas = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                    if (canvas == null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Cannot lock canvas, skipping MJpeg frame");
                        return;
                    }
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

                    Rect dst = null;
                    int viewWidth = mPreview.getWidth();
                    int viewHeight = mPreview.getHeight();
                    float ratio = bmp.getWidth() / (float)bmp.getHeight();
                    int desiredHeight = (int)(viewWidth / ratio);
                    if (desiredHeight > viewHeight)
                    {   // Letterbox
                        int maxWidth = (int)(viewHeight * ratio);
                        int pad = (viewWidth - maxWidth) / 2;
                        dst = new Rect(pad, 0, maxWidth + pad, viewHeight);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int pad = (viewHeight - desiredHeight) / 2;
                        dst = new Rect(0, pad, viewWidth, desiredHeight + pad);
                    }

                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, dst, null);
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`canvas = holder.lockCanvas(null);` looks suspect.

Try `canvas = holder.lockCanvas();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are adding a "Pad" to the destination rectangle to change it's height.

If you do that, I wonder if the destination rectangle size will match the size of the image you are drawing and thus "over draw" some gray bar as you are seeing. Just a guess - maybe if you remove the height pad it will go away? Just a guess.

```
dst = new Rect(0, pad, viewWidth, desiredHeight + pad);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, dst, null);
```

Comment: the padding just gives me the appropriate height. This little gray "bar" doesn't even cover the entire width of the jpeg. Just the bottom right corner of it and the trail end of it is pixelated.  Are there any BitmapFactory options that might help?